# It is possible to restore deleted file in Gnat Studio

Tags: file, ada, restore, gnat

I accidentally deleted a file in the project and was surprised to find that I didn't know how to get it back. It's not in the trash. It's good that the file was not important. Can you please tell me if there is a way to restore a deleted file, or at least protect it from deletion?

Comment: I just wonder how the file was deleted. I believe that a file can not be deleted from within Gnat Studio since there is no delete file menu available. In addition, there is a lock icon at the lower right just below the editor pane. It can be locked to prevent accidental file contents deletion.

Comment: @AnhVo, In the Project View, right click on a file and then select File Operations -> Delete Selected Files. There's also a keyboard shortcut (seems to be Backspace by default). But there will be a confirmation dialog, so it's hard to imagine deleting by accident, though

Comment: @egihh, thank you for this info. I did not realize it is there. It may be useful in some rare case.

Comment: I just did a quick test. As long as the file is locked by clicking the lock icon, file deletion operation is not successful. In other word, the file will not be deleted.

Comment: @AnhVo, I do the same thing, but file may be deleted anyway. What version of editor you use?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not programming-related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that GnatStudio has nothing to do with this, file deletion is done by your OS and Gnat studio just uses the services/APIs  that your OS provides to do that.  If you work on Linux, I guess that GS deletes the file by calling unlink(), not moving it to some trash.

- You can try some "undelete" software for your OS. It is not guaranteed to work, but if you did not made many changes to your filesystem, it can do a decent work. (I do not use this type of software myself, so I cannot give you suggestions)
- If your sources are under version control (e.g., git, bazaar, svn, mercurial, ...) you can at least recover the latest commit of your file. How to do that depends on your VC software.